# CLI versus gemfile syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gemfile

Using the command line interface, I can do the following:

```
gem install mysql2 --platform=ruby -- '--with-mysql-dir="C:/mysql-connector/"'
```

What would be the gemfile equivalent. Reading through the docs, I got as far as:

```
 gem 'mysql2', :platforms => :ruby
```

Any ideas? Looking through the manual, it's not clear what the syntax is

Comment: so, to be more specific you are asking "how do I add custom arguments to the gemfile"

Comment: the line `gem 'mysql2', :platforms => :ruby` is required for bundler, not for command line

Answer (score 0):

These options can't be specified inside of Gemfile. Use `bundle config` instead. Here's the [guide](http://bundler.io/v1.2/bundle_config.html) (section 'Build options'). There's an example for mysql gem:

```
gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
```

Instead of code above, you can do the following:

```
bundle config build.mysql --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
```

So, every time you will install mysql gem, it will pass these parameters. And, yes, it will work with simple `bundle install`.